# How can one change this recurrence relation to be in terms of the first value of a?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, recurrence-relations, bessel-functions

How does one put the recurrence relation:$$a_{2k}=\frac{(-1)^k}{4kl+2k(k+1)}a_{2k-2}$$
Where $l$ is any non-negative integer. In terms of $a_0$ so that:$$a_{2k}=\frac{(-1)^k}{f(k)}a_0$$

Answer (score 0):

As you have 
$$
a_{2k}=\frac{(-1)^ka_{2k-2}}{2k(2l+k+1)}
$$
you also get
$$
(-1)^{k(k+1)/2}2^k\Gamma(k+1)\Gamma(2l+k+2)a_{2k}
\\
=(-1)^{k(k-1)/2}2^{k-1}\Gamma(k)\Gamma(2l+k+1)a_{2k-2}
$$
which gives you a constant, and thus is equal to the term for $k=1$,
$$
…=\Gamma(2l+1)a_{0}
$$

Comment: This looks really good. Is there any chance you could explain the steps between the top equation and the second line please?

Comment: Use $\Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x)$ and $\sum_{j=1}^kj=k(k+1)/2$, i.e., the usual recursive definitions. Account for every factor on the right with some quotient $f(k+1)/f(k)$.