# How can one put this recurrence relation in terms of the first value of a?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, recurrence-relations, bessel-functions

How does one put the recurrence relation:$$a_{2k}=\frac{(-1)^k}{4kl+2k(2k+1)}a_{2k-2}$$

Where $l$ is a non-negative integer. In terms of $a_0$ so that:$$a_{2k}=\frac{(-1)^kg(k)}{f(k)}a_0$$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2040680/115115 for a quite similar question